# Trying to get base64 png image into p5.js image

Tags: javascript, p5.js

So as the title says, i'm trying to load a base64 encoded png image into a p5js image, here's a simplification of how im doing it:

PS: I'm using a base64 image because it's generated from a server

```
var img;
function setup() {
  // Canvas setup code ....

  img = loadImage('loading.png'); // show an image which says that it's loading
  img.loadPixels();

  // More setup code ...
}


// ...

function draw() {
  image(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
  // ... more code
}

// ...

function receivedCallback(data) { // This function gets called once we receive the data
  // Data looks like this: { width: 100, height: 100, data: "...base64 data...." }
  img.resize(data.width, data.height);
  var imgData = data.data;
  var imgBlob = new Blob([imgData], { type: "image/png" }); // Create a blob
  var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL(imgBlob); // Craft the url
  img.src = imageUrl;
  img.loadPixels();
  img.updatePixels();
}
```

But, it's not working which is why I am asking here.
If there is any way to do it I would appreciate it very much.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
Steve's didn't *quite* work, I had to replace `img.src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + data.data` with `img = loadImage('data:image/png;base64,' + data.data);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steve's didn't *quite* work, I had to load the image instead of directly changing it's source.
So instead of `img.src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + data.data`.

I needed to do `img = loadImage('data:image/png;base64,' + data.data);`

Thanks to Steve for his answer though!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Data URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) directly. It can look something like this:

```
function receivedCallback(data) { // This function gets called once we receive the data
  // Data looks like this: { width: 100, height: 100, data: "...base64 data...." }
  loadImage('data:image/png;base64,' + data.data, function (newImage) {
    img = newImage;
  });
}
```

If you need to use blobs for some reason, you can look into base64 to blob conversions, like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16245768/).

Comment: Sadly, it didn't work

Comment: Ah, looking into the p5 api, you might not be updating the image correctly. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference between loading a base64 image and a regular image from a file in P5.js. Simply replace the URL in your [`loadImage`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadImage) call with the base64 data.

In the interests of a runnable, complete example (note that the base64 image is very small):

```js
const imgData = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAIAQMAAAD+wSzIAAAABlBMVEX///+/v7+jQ3Y5AAAADklEQVQI12P4AIX8EAgALgAD/aNpbtEAAAAASUVORK5CYII";
let img;

function preload() {
  img = loadImage(imgData);
}

function draw() {
  image(img, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

If your data is supposed to load at some indeterminate point in the future, say, after an interaction, then you can use a callback to determine when the image has loaded. This is somewhat use-case specific, but the pattern might look like:

```js
const imgData = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAIAQMAAAD+wSzIAAAABlBMVEX///+/v7+jQ3Y5AAAADklEQVQI12P4AIX8EAgALgAD/aNpbtEAAAAASUVORK5CYII";
let img;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(300, 300);
}

function draw() {
  clear();
  textSize(14);
  text("click to load image", 10, 10);

  if (img) {
    image(img, 0, 0);
  }
}

function mousePressed() {
  if (!img) {
    loadImage(imgData, imgResult => {
      img = imgResult;
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

If you have some async code in there, no problem. Just call `loadImage` whenever you have the base64 string ready, for example:

```
function mousePressed() {
  if (!img) {
    fetch("your endpoint")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {  
        // prepend "data:image/png;base64," if
        // `data.data` doesn't already have it
        loadImage(data.data, imgResult => {
          img = imgResult;
        });
      });
  }
}
```

All this said, loading an image in response to a click is a somewhat odd pattern for most apps. Usually, you'd want to preload all of your asssets in the `preload` function so that you can render them immediately when requested. If you load via a `fetch` call in response to an event, there'll likely be an ugly-looking delay (or needing to show a temporary message/placeholder image/spinner) before rendering the image, so make sure this isn't an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676).